# Ubuntu installation for previous versions. (16.04.4)

Tags: release-management

I want to install Ubuntu 16.04.4 version from archive.ubuntu.com repository. however i could always install only 16.04.5..is there a specific method where i can install previous versions within a major version?

Answer (score 1):

16.04.4 went EOL when 16.04.5 got released and that means it gets moved to  the [archives server](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/16.04.4/). All the versions from 16.04 through 16.04.4 can be found there.

Comment: Hi Rinzwind, thanks for your prompt response. however i guess these are all live CD's.. i want to build a repository based on 16.04.4 and install through pxe. in these ISO image, i see only pre-extracted files.

Comment: I don't get that from the question. But nevertheless: there are no official repositories for end of life versions, only installers.